# Unity - Debug.DrawRay keeps drawing lines on every Update call

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a skeleton game object which I make move by increasing its velocity on the `Update` function, like this:

```
body.velocity = new Vector2((isFacingLeft ? -1 : 1) * speed, body.velocity.y);
```

Which is also controlled by a direction `isFacingLeft`, which determines movement for the skeleton from left to right.

```
int direction = isFacingLeft ? -1 : 1;
```

But, since my skeleton is in a platform, I want to use a ray cast to ensure I detect whenever no platform is in front (so the cast points diagonally down in front of the skeleton), so I prepare a few variables to ensure I have a proper position for the ray cast. Then, if no floor has been found, the `isFacingLeft` variable is flipped, so the skeleton moves in the opposite direction as it approaches an edge:

```
 Vector2 beginFloorCast = new Vector2(transform.position.x + ((enemyWidth / 2) * direction), transform.position.y - enemyHeight / 2);
 Vector2 floorCastDirection = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector2(1 * (direction), -1));
 float floorCastLength = 1f;

 RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(beginFloorCast, floorCastDirection, floorCastLength);

 if (!hit) {
   isFacingLeft = !isFacingLeft;
 }
```

While this all works, I am now trying to draw a debug ray so I can visualize in debug mode how long the floor ray is (and so I can use this in the future to detect if the player is in range of the skeleton with another ray), so I use the following:

```
Debug.DrawRay(beginFloorCast, floorCastDirection.normalized * floorCastLength, Color.green, 5f);
```

This also works, but in the Scene mode, the ray is drawn once for every Update call:

[image]

Is there a way for me to clear the debug screen after the `Update` function is done? Or what could I change in my code to make sure I only call it once and that the ray follows the skeleton?

Comment: You want to have only one debug ray visible at once? That 5f, in `Debug.DrawRay(beginFloorCast, floorCastDirection.normalized * floorCastLength, Color.green, 5f);` makes it to last 5 seconds. Delete that parameter, it defaults to 0 seconds.

Comment: You were right. Removing that `5f` made the debug rays disappear and look like they're following the skeleton. Thanks!